# How can i check out only parts of the repository in bazaar?

Tags: bazaar

In Subversion I can checkout a sub-tree of the repository. Can I do something similar with bazaar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do a partial clone/branch with either bazaar, mercurial or git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298332/is-it-possible-to-do-a-partial-clone-branch-with-either-bazaar-mercurial-or-git)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not posible at the moment although there are plans to add this in future releases.